# Unable to select all records where used_id NOT IN $admin_ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a number of rows providing the user id's in $admin_ID are not present.

```
$admin_ID = "1, 32, 34";
foreach($con->query('SELECT user_agent FROM wp_access_log WHERE user_id NOT IN ($admin_ID)') as $row2) {  
    $user_agent2 = $row2['user_agent'];
    $browser2 = new BrowserDetection();
    $browser2->setUserAgent($user_agent2);
    $browserName2  = $browser2->getPlatform();                //string
    $browserNameString2[] = $browserName2;
}

$string = var_export(array_count_values($browserNameString2), true);

echo "<table id='datatable-buttons' class='table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>";
    echo "<tr><td><b>Browser</b></td><td><b>Visits</b></td></tr>";
    $string = str_replace("array (","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("' => ","</td><td>",$string);
    $string = str_replace(",","</td></tr>",$string);
    $string = str_replace(")","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("'","<tr><td>",$string);
$string = $string . "</table>";
echo $string;
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\account-stats.php on line 543
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: browserNameString2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\account-stats.php on line 553
>
> Warning: array_count_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\account-stats.php on line 553
>   NULL

If I remove the code:

```
 WHERE user_id NOT IN ($admin_ID)
```

Then the code runs fine and loads all records from the database.

Can I get a pointer as to what I have done wrong here?

Comment: $browsernamestring2 works perfectly fine if i just try to retrieve all records. Its when i use the " WHERE user_id NOT IN ($admin_ID)" that im getting a problem

Comment: @SandyBeach, you're not checking for any errors or handling any edge cases like 0 results.  Chances are, your error would be exposed if you were.

Comment: `$admin_ID` needs to be treated as an array, and possibly imploded.

Comment: @chris85 I think this is also about what I said; the OP isn't treating that initial variable as an array, unless there's something I'm not grasping.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is a string though, no?

Comment: @chris85 I tend to agree, yes. However, they're looking to see if any of those 3 are part of their IN query. Seeing the answer below though..........

Comment: @Fred-ii- Shouldn't that work, it'd be `SELECT user_agent FROM wp_access_log WHERE user_id NOT IN (1, 32, 34)` (if double quoted)

Comment: @chris85 Yepper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PHP` variable interpolation works only if interpolated string is double quotes. So `PHP` doesn't substitutes `$admin_ID` value in your `SQL` query which is placed between sigle quotes, and you get an incorrect query. Place your query in double quotes:

`"SELECT user_agent FROM wp_access_log WHERE user_id NOT IN ($admin_ID)"`

Comment: Ah thanks for explaining that, your right changed to double quotes and it works perfectly now.